# Show one Popover on mouseenter event at a time (Angular, ngBootstrap)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have dynamically generated divs. On those divs, i have ngPopovers. Inside ngPopover, i have button and i want to click on button button. So i have triggered ng popover like this `triggers="mouseenter"`.

Here is code for view

```
 <div [ngbPopover]="popContent"  class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-secondary" 
 ngbPopover="<button>Hello</button>" triggers="mouseenter"  >
     Hover over me!
 </div>


 <div [ngbPopover]="popContent" class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-secondary"           
 ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover!" triggers="mouseenter"  
 (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" >
 Hover over me!
  </div>

 <div [ngbPopover]="popContent" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
 ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover!" triggers="mouseenter">
 Hover over me!
 </div>


<ng-template #popContent>
<div>
    <button> Cancel </button>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

Now popover is visible, but if i hover on another div(Div other than the popover container), the previous popover should be hidden and new popover should be visible if i hover any other div containing the popover.

Please tell me, how can show one popover at a time. 
Here is a working fiddle/stack blitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4dgz1?file=app/popover-triggers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HostListner to listen mousleave event on document then use @ViewChild Decorator to get the Element ref

```
 @HostListener('mouseleave',['$event']) onHoverOutside(){
   this.ref.close();
  }
```

Check the Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4dgz1-3w7f3p

Comment: Hello @chellappan.  Thank you for the reply. Please read the description again. I want to click on the button, icannot use `:mouseleave` If i use `:mouseleave`, i will not be able to click on button

Comment: Hello @Chellappan, Thank you for sharing updated code. The code you shared have following error: `Property 'close' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'`

Comment: remove ElementRef from the ViewChild it wil go

Comment: Thank you.. Yes it removed the error. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention mouseleave as well. Like this:

```
<div [ngbPopover]="popContent"  class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-secondary" 
 ngbPopover="<button>Hello</button>" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"  >
     Hover over me!
 </div>


 <div [ngbPopover]="popContent" class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-secondary"           
 ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover!" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"  
 (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" >
 Hover over me!
  </div>

 <div [ngbPopover]="popContent" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
 ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover!" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">
 Hover over me!
 </div>


<ng-template #popContent>
<div>
    <button> Cancel </button>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: please read the description once again. I have button inside popover and i cannot use `:mouseleave` as i need to click on button.

Comment: "Now popover is visible, but if i hover on another div, the previous popover should be hidden and new popover should be visible."  This statement in your question implies that you want to hide the popover when you hover on another div. Not on button click

Comment: Yes i mean, if i hover on any other div,, Other then the div containing Popover