# How to click hovered element in angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

This is the code where I want to bind click event to the hovered contents. My goal is to let the hovered contents stay still so that I will be able to click on the anchor tags used.

```
<td>
    <ng-template #popContent>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Contain</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Triage</a></li>
                <li><a href="">File Acq</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Acquistion</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <button
       (mouseenter)="changeClass = !changeClass;" (mouseleave)="changeClass = !changeClass;"
       class="btn actionButton"
       triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
       [style.opacity] = "getStyle()"
       placement="left"
       popoverClass="popover"
       [ngbPopover]=popContent > <img src="assets/images/dots.png">
    </button>
</td>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655768/show-one-popover-on-mouseenter-event-at-a-time-angular-ngbootstrap/51655864#51655864

Comment: Thank you. But i have an doubt. i could not get your comment. "remove ElementRef from the ViewChild it will go" in that question. Please make it clear

Comment: i have removed  the ElementRef from stackbkitz code

Comment: I have written exactly the way you have written. But still i am getting the same error.
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined" This is the error i am getting.

Comment: Can you show your html code

Comment: I am facing one more Problem . Here i am using it with a <td> element.Here when mouse is leaving the button its not reacting immediately, after leaving the column the mouseleave is working.

Comment: Can you please help me in creating another component in a single .ts file

Comment: what do you mean by creating new component ?

Comment: You adviced to create directive..So please help me out in creating one.

Comment: Sure wait i wil

Comment: Please help me in Solving this error . ""ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined""

Comment: can you share your code